# Definition of a Bernoulli Number(& Contour Integral)

Tags: integration, derivatives

So I'm a little confused on where the Bernoulli numbers come from. Most of the definitions involve contour integrals, which I can't define and understand as well as I thought, though I do know regular integration. So, where do the Bernoulli  numbers come from? Also, what is a contour integral really?

Comment: According to Wikipedia [Bernoulli number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number) from Jakob Bernoulli. The article does **not** mention any contour integrals. Do you have a reference?

Comment: In Wolfram Math Alpha, they gave a definition of the Bernoulli numbers in terms of contour integrals

Comment: What do you mean by "come from"?

Comment: As in, how are the Bernoulli numbers calculated?

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean the same as equation (2) of the MathWorld [Bernoulli Number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliNumber.html) article, essentially equivalent to the exponential generating function in equation (1). Read the Wikipedia article [Laurent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) for the equivalence. Of course, there are easier ways of calculating Bernoulli numbers going back before Jakob Bernoulli. See the Wikipedia article [Bernoulli number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number) for more details and references.